# What is the code for inserting lengthy mutli-line text as d3.js nodes (several hundred words)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm seen various posts and how to word wrap text longer than an arbitrary pixel length, but is it possible to have blocks of text several hundred words long as the node without having to preconvert it to an image (as images are possible).

Comment: What do you mean by "as the node"?

Comment: The circles in http://www.d3noob.org/2013/03/d3js-force-directed-graph-examples.html

Comment: Yes, use e.g. `foreignObject`s with `div`s.